# Java - Java mail error - javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Server Unavailable. 15

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, microsoft-exchange

I am using a java program to connect to a mailbox and read Emails from a folder in the mailbox. I am using `Java Mail 1.5.6` and Java 8. Below is my code for connecting:

```
IMAPSSLStore returnImapConnectStore() throws InvalidKeyException,
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
    IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
    AuthenticationFailedException, IllegalStateException {

        IMAPSSLStore store = null;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");

        String host = "imapmail.company.com";
        final String username = "username";

        final String password = "password"


        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                            password);
                }
            });

            session.setDebug(true);
            store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, null);
            store.connect(host, 993, username, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Connection to server error.....");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (store);
    }
```

The program worked fine until there was a change in the password for the `username`. When I updated the password and ran the program, I get the following error:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imapmail.company.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imapmail.company.com, user=username, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO Server Unavailable. 15
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imapmail.company.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imapmail.company.com, user=username, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO Server Unavailable. 15
Connection to server error.....
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Server Unavailable. 15
                at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:725)
                at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
```

I tried using the old password again and it gives me :
`DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO LOGIN failed.
Connection to server error.....
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.`

I am not sure how I should solve this error. I searched online but didn't find any useful resources for my problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider that perhaps it's not actually able to reach your server?

Comment: When I use a wrong password, it gives me `Login Failed` and when I try a different hostname to connect to, it gives `java.net.UnknownHostException`. So I assumed it was connecting to the server.@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: There is probably something wrong with maildir structure or some other error server side. You need to talk to mail server admin or look in the logs yourself if you can.

Comment: While you're fixing things, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).